# Qual è il significato di "agguantare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> «Eravamo soli in sala. Madonna Tuzia batteva il tagliere in cucina. Dissi, ho la febbre, lasciatemi stare. Disse, ho più febbre di voi; e mi prese per mano, volle che andassimo avanti e indietro passeggiando: l'uscio della mia camera era aperto. Mi tenne a forza sul letto con le pugna e coi denti, ma io avevo visto sulla cassa il coltellino di Francesco, mi allungai, lo *agguantai*, e menavo di sotto in su, tagliandomi la palma.»

Con queste parole Artemisia Gentileschi descrive lo strupo subito da parte di Agostino Tassi quando lei era un'adolescente. Non capisco bene il senso che ha il verbo "agguantare" nel brano precedente. Si referisce forse a [questa accezione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/agguantare/) che ho trovato nel vocabolario Treccani?

> Nell’uso fam., anche colpire giusto: *se l’agguantava con quella sassata, gli spaccava la testa*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo brano, il significato è il principale: "prendere, afferrare rapidamente, con forza". Artemisia si allunga, prende il coltellino di Francesco e lo agita, lo muove ("menavo").

Comment: Grazie: adesso capisco molto meglio il significato del brano!

Comment: @Charo Si risponde *a* una domanda! :-)